# Universal parameters in c++ function?

Tags: c++, function, variables, parameters

I have a function1 that takes whatever parameters you give it and display it:

```
void function1(string a){
    std::cout << a;
}

void function1(int a){
    std::cout << a;
}

void function1(double a){
    std::cout << a;
}

void function1(char a){
cout << a;
}
void function1(float a){
    std::cout << a;
}
```

is there a way to call for a kind of universal variable so i dont need to write so much code?

Something like this:

```
void function1(UNIVERSAL a){
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Comment: Read up on templates.

Comment: Funny thing, if terse concept syntax will make its way to the standard, we could write code exactly as written in example by defining a catch-all `UNIVERSAL` concept.

Comment: @user0042 I do not think that this is a good dupe. While it explains where to get learning material, it does not explain what templates are and why they are applicable it this situation at all.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Yeah, I wondered myself why there's not yet a better to be found. May be time to write a canonical Q&A or improve this question to be one.

Answer (score 4):

[Templates do *exactly* this!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates)

```
template <typename T>
void function1(T const &t) {
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}

int main() {
    function1(123);
    function1(45.67);
    function1("foobar");
}
```

Prints:

```
123
45.67
foobar
```

Note a couple of things:

1. This requires whatever type you call it with to support the `<<` syntax. If it doesn't, you might get some pretty cryptic error messages.
2. I pass the parameter by reference-to-`const`, since you are supporting any type, and you don't know if it will be very large or expensive to copy.

When writing a template, think carefully about what you want to require of the types you are using it with. The requirements are determined by the things you do in the function implementation. Don't inadvertently introduce new requirements when you add to the function.

Comment: GREAT! this did it ! Thanks very much BobTFish and Neil Butterworth!